# Proguard questions

Tags: proguard

Did you do two issues in proguard.

- **Change words or phrases**

It is possible to outshine eg certain words or phrases in a class?
**Example:**

`throw new QualaRuntimeException ("License invalid");`

For example, I liked that the obfuscated code does not appear on the License is invalid, because then you can see that I'm doing a validation license.

I like to appears throw new QualaRuntimeException ("**_**");

- **Change name package**

It's possible to change the name of a particular package where the class?

**Example:**

pt.teste.license.Licenca

I Like to stay something like: XXX.Licenca...

Answer (score 0):

- This is string encryption/obfuscation. ProGuard doesn't provide it, but you could implement it yourself, with some string manipulation, e.g. Base64 encoding or something less trivial. Commercial obfuscators can do it for you, probably more conveniently and effectively, e.g. ProGuard's extension for Android, [DexGuard](http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard).
- ProGuard supports moving obfuscated classes to a single package:

  ```
  -repackageclasses xyz
  ```

  You may need to let ProGuard change the access flags of the code:

  ```
  -allowaccessmodification
  ```

  See the ProGuard manual > Examples > [Obfuscating package names](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#repackaging)

(I am the developer of ProGuard and DexGuard)

Comment: Hi Eric one more question. What do the option adaptresourcefilecontent? I have in file x.tld `<tag>
    <name>param</name>
    <tag-class>pt.data.taglibs.ParamTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>JSP</body-content>
    <description>     
  Parametros para a tag de parametros
    </description>
    
    <attribute>
        <name>value</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>   
  </tag>`.  I obfuscaste the class pt.data.taglibs.ParamTag. Is possible modify in x.tdl for new name class?